# jQuery .css() borderRadius not working in FF(3.6) and IE(6,7) on Windows

Tags: jquery, css

The following code doesn't seem to work in FF(3.6) and IE(7) on Windows XP.

```
$("#myDiv").css({
  mozBorderRadius: "6px",
  webkitBorderRadius: "6px",
  borderRadius: "6px"   
});
```

Is there anything I can do to make this work?

C

Comment: IE7 doesn't have border radius, I think images are usually used or some hacky DX transform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE7 doesn't understand border-radius, so the CSS is ignored. You can either live with it, or try to find a fancy solution to render rounded corders using images.

I would choose the first, although there are numerous examples ([like this one](http://www.devinrolsen.com/rounded-corners-with-css-and-one-image/)) out there if you really need rounded corners in those old browsers.

FF 3.6 does support rounded corders, but you should use `-moz-border-radius` for that.

Comment: It should work in Firefox 3.6, though. Perhaps it should be "MozBorderRadius"?

Comment: it should be `-moz-border-radius`, according to Google.

Comment: @Brent Thanks... MozBorderRadius sorted the issue in FF 3.6

Answer (score 2):

for Firefox, [as GolezTrol said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794438/jquery-css-borderradius-not-working-in-ff3-6-and-ie6-7-on-windows/7794466#7794466), it should be `-moz-border-radius` (or `MozBorderRadius`) instead of `mozBorderRadius`. unfortunatelly, IE 6 and 7 both don't support `border-radius` so you have to work around that by:

- using images instead

or, for the lazy ones:

- using [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/). you only have to add one line to the stylesheet for elements that could have `border-radius`:

  ```
  behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc);
  ```

  note that this solution also allows you to use `box-shadow` and linear gradients wich might also be useful. just take a look at the [demo](http://css3pie.com/demos/tabs/).